# Problems with internationalization using MVC filter

Tags: c#, .net, resx, asp.net-mvc-filters

I have an .NET 4.5.2 application with localized resource files (Messages.resx (for pt), Messages.es.resx and Messages.en.resx).

An MVC filter sets the thread culture based on client language.

I've published on a farm with 3 servers and it worked fine for some time, and suddenly the following behavior started:

- One of the servers began to respond requests with pt culture with english messages.
- Besides that, messages that are not translated to english and are only on Messages.resx file are returning empty.
- If the client language is es the server returns with spanish messages.

We changed the farm servers and that happened on 4 different servers.

I tried to include [assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguage("pt")] on AssemblyInfo but the problem still happens.

Could anyone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

'An MVC filter sets the thread culture based on client language.'

Why? IIS can do this automatically.
Use:

```
<globalization uiCulture="auto" culture="auto" />
```

in the system.web section of your web.config